# error reporting issues

Tags: php, error-reporting

I'm still entangled in error handling problems. After having read and tried lots of different scripts, I still do not have an overall insight on the problem.

I made a syntax error on purpose and get the following error message :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/directory/public_html/mypage.php on line 10
```

To understand how it work, as a first step, I'd like to remove this message(which I'am able to do) and replace it by a custom one.

How can I customize this message ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to add a bit more detail on the background, each question should ideally stand on its own. Trawling through your past questions to work out context is not likely to be something people are going to do.

Comment: I was not asking anyone to trawl through my past questions. On the contrary,my question is clear,simple and stupid (at least for those who know the answer). Getting some feedback would help me taking a step forward. How to customize a standard PHP error message into something more secure and user friendly? "php_flag display_errors off" removes display but leaves the browser empty. Thanks again.

Comment: Parse errors are exactly the ones that can't be customized ;-) there might be other fatal errors though.

Comment: I'd like to rank Jack's comment as a usefull answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). It enables you to catch thrown erros and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Do you mean Parse errors can NEVER be caught in any way, even with exception handling ?